# In a linux appliance generated by VMware Studio, where is the subsequent boot script located?

Tags: centos, virtualization

I have a vmware appliance (linux, centos 5) generated by Vmware Studio. I can't figure out where vmware studio places the commands entered into the "Subsequent Boot" field. Any ideas?

More specific info: In the xml file that defines the appliance, there is this item:

*Subsequent Boot Script: Shell script that is executed when the appliance boots up each time except for the first  
time. 
//ovf:Envelope/Section[@xsi:type='vadk:ApplicationSection_Type']/vadk:BootActions/vadk: 
SubsequentBoot*

I'm interested in knowing which file these actions are persisted to in the virtual appliance.

I have looked in /etc/rc.d and haven't found it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

/etc/rc.local would be my first guess, but you might just want to try searching /etc

Add something obvious, eg:

```
echo "TEST SubsequentBoot"
```

Then grep /etc/ for it:

```
grep -r SubsequentBoot /etc
```

If it's not in /etc try looking in /var, /boot, /opt, /usr/local (rough order of liklihood)

Answer (score 1):

I finally located the file here: /opt/vmware/etc/isv/subsequentboot.
The firstboot xml item is also placed here.

Comment: One thing I believe is worth mentioning is that there has to be a flag in `/opt/vmware/etc/vami/flags/vami_runbootscripts`, otherwise the scripts won't run.